# Two buttons in different forms side by side

Tags: html, css

i have two forms. One form for login and the other form for reset the password.
Now i want to set the both buttons (login, password reset) side by side.

But i don't know, how to do that.

[image: Here is a picture of my layout]
And here is my code:

```html
<form action="login" method="POST">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Username:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" aria-describedby="important" />
            </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Passwort:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" aria-describedby="important" />
          </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
   <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-default" value="Login" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<form action="reset" method="POST">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
   <input class="form-control btn-default" type="submit" value="Passwort vergessen" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: why you want reset button in different form?

Comment: Why not just have `<input name="type" type="submit" class="form-control btn-default" value="Login" />
    <input name="type" class="form-control btn-default" type="submit" value="Passwort vergessen" />` and test `$type=="login"` or `$type=="Passwort vergessen"` on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the button elements in same form and add `form` attribute to the other button to which you want to associate with other form element.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

> The form element that the button is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a  element in the same document. If this attribute is not specified, the  element will be associated to an ancestor  element, if one exists. This attribute enables you to associate  elements to  elements anywhere within a document, not just as descendants of  elements.

Example:

```
<form id="firstForm">
     <button>Submit First form</button>
     <button form="secondForm">Submit Second form</button>
</form>

<form id="secondForm">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your second form an id (e.g. "form2"), and add this CSS:

```
#form2 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the buttons side by side you can add the css property `float: left;` to the login button and it'll work, but it'll work only for this example.

```html
<form action="login" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Username:</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" aria-describedby="important" />
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Passwort:</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" aria-describedby="important" />
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
      <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-default" value="Login" style="float:left; />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form action="reset" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
      <input class="form-control btn-default" type="submit" value="Passwort vergessen" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Important note:**
I don't think it's a good idea to use a form only for a button element, you should think of using it in the same form and apply the float: left; property to the buttons, it makes more sense and it's better for your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

i changed css of two buttons, now it works, here you can run, nd see it's working now.

i added `style="float:left;"` in `<input type="submit" class="form-control btn-default" value="Login"/>` and `<input class="form-control btn-default" type="submit" value="Passwort vergessen"/>`

```html
<form action="login" method="POST">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Username:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" aria-describedby="important" />
            </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Passwort:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" aria-describedby="important" />
          </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
   <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-default" value="Login" style="float:left;" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<form action="reset" method="POST">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
   <input class="form-control btn-default" type="submit" value="Passwort vergessen" style="float:left;" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Better way to do**

You should not use a second form to reset your first form.

You have to use only one form and add an input with `type="reset"`

By this way you can place your buttons `side by side` in only one line and `reset` works !

```
<div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-default" value="Login" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</div>
```

**Live demo** :
https://jsfiddle.net/20o2ahnr/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#resetForm {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 37px;
    left: 55px;

}
</style>
<form action="login" method="POST">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Username:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" aria-describedby="important" />
            </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Passwort:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 input-group input-group-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="important">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" />
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" aria-describedby="important" />
          </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
   <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-default" value="Login" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<form action="reset" method="POST">
 <div class="row" id="resetForm">
  <div class="col-md-2 input-group-sm">
   <input class="form-control btn-default" type="submit" value="Passwort vergessen" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```